Why an error come when I go check the conda versions?
Why is the error heppening? I expect without error to show the version. Please provide me with the solutions.

(base) C:\Users\chowd>conda --version
Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth (cannot import name 'ChannelAuthBase' from 'conda.plugins.types' (C:\Users\chowd\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py))
Error while loading conda entry point: anaconda-cloud-auth (cannot import name 'ChannelAuthBase' from 'conda.plugins.types' (C:\Users\chowd\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py))
conda 23.7.4


Have you tried updating conda?
conda update conda
